# Android Studio Não roda o script ( KVM MISSING )

Tags: android, android-studio, emulador

Bom dia, tenho o Android Studio rodando no meu Windows normal , o emulador também funciona.
Instalei na VMBOX da oracle o debian, no processador habilitei a opção de VT-X/AMD-V
instalei o andorid studio mais o emulador com nexus 5 mas na hora de executar ele diz que não tenho suporte ao KVM

ja tentei instalar os pacotes do KVM na mão , e dei uma "googada" sobre o assunto mas todas saídas que achei foram para ubuntu e não debian 8

Alguém sabe como proceder?

no meu terminal rodei

```
egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

e o retorno foi 0

Answer (score 1):

Se você rodou o comando `egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo` e retornou `"0"` é porque seu processador não tem suporte para executar o kvm.